# How to make %in% work with characters in R?

Tags: r, string

Being from Python background, and seeing this example in R documentation:

```
 #%in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, 
 #which returns a logical vector indicating if 
 #there is a match or not for its left operand.

1:10 %in% c(1,3,5,9)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I am trying to convert the string to list:

```
"(" %in% as.list("(62473575, 62474092)")  # does not work 

"(" %in% strsplit("(62473575, 62474092)", "") # kind of works half way
```

and getting `FALSE`. What is going on?

PS: I do not want to use grep, (1) as it treats `"("` as a special character and (2) I am looking for exact match, not a regular expression.

Comment: You have to use `grep`. Just escape "(" as follows: `grep("\\(", "(62473575, 62474092)")`

Comment: I am looking for exact match of "(" with element "("? Why does it fail and how can one fix it?

Comment: Notice that `c(1,3,5,9)` is a vector of _four_ elements. `"(62473575, 62474092)"` is a _length-one_ string.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: notice I am trying to convert it to a list or vector; `as.list` does not work, `strsplit` kind of works but finally fails

Comment: "finally fails" meaning what

Comment: My guess: you want `strsplit("(62473575, 62474092)", "")[[1]]`.

Comment: @ MichaelChirico: it worked. Can you post an answer and explain why is it so nested?

Comment: Because it's designed to work on vectors. Look at `strsplit(c("(123)", "(456789)"), "")` to understand why.

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear this is what you want. What is wrong with `grepl`? That approach is much better for most situations

Comment: it is just not logical why it is so complicated with `%in%` from Python perspective. I see `grep` will work, but it is a more complex, why not use a simpler approach? I just could not get first that it needs two backslashes.

Comment: I see it turns into a bit more philosophical chat why logical is better than unlogical or why simple better than complicatd. `%in%` should do the job, as I am looking for exact match, not regex. I always use `in` in Python and it works. But just R makes it complicated.

Comment: "why is it so complicated?" is a long conversation. There are two parts here: (1) R's paradigm for string-handling is arguably not as convenient as Python's; (2) R's paradigm for string-handling is **different** from Python's. "Why is it so hard to do x in language y?" often indicates that you're failing to switch idioms between languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to find the positions of the ')' characters in the string.

There are two problems are present with your `strsplit` approach.
You have the arguments to `%in%` reversed, and `strsplit` returns a list.

```
unlist(strsplit("(62473575, 62474092)", "")) %in% ')'
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Equivalently, because you have a single element on the right-hand side:

```
unlist(strsplit("(62473575, 62474092)", "")) == ')'
```

If, on the other hand, you want to see if ')' is present in a vector of strings, you can use `sapply` on the return value of `strsplit`, which returns a list of vectors, each vector being the split value of each string in the input vector:

```
x <- c('abc', 'ab(cd)')
sapply(strsplit(x, ''), FUN=function(y) ')' %in% y)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Equivalently, using `grepl`:

```
grepl(')', x, fixed=TRUE)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Note the `fixed` argument.